# xcode - why is a warning of 'is hidden' given with overloaded virtual functions

Tags: c++, warnings, virtual, hidden

I have a base class e.g.:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void methodA(int) {}
  virtual void methodA(int, int, int) {}
};
```

xcode gives out warnings of methodA was hidden - everything sems works as I'd expect (classes derived from A can be accessed via an A pointer and use either of the methodA's).

Comment: warning is not from XCode it is from your compiler.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Yes, the compiler being clang++ (unless this is an old version of Xcode), and being thighly integrated into the Xcode environment... I would not be surprised if Xcode actually produced that warning before even clicking on 'compile' :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess one of the classes derived from `A` (let's say it's `B`) only overrides one of the overloads of `methodA()`. In this case, the other overload of `methodA` is *hidden* in `B`. Example:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void methodA(int) {}
  virtual void methodA(int, int, int) {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  virtual void methodA(int) {}
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  A *pa = &b;
  a.methodA(7); //OK
  a.methodA(7, 7, 7); //OK
  pa->methodA(7);  //OK, calls B's implementation
  pa->methodA(7, 7, 7);  //OK, calls A's implementation
  b.methodA(7); //OK
  b.methodA(7, 7, 7);  //compile error - B's methodA only accepts one int, not three.
}
```

The solution is to add a `using` declaration into `B`:

```
class B : public A {
public:
  using A::methodA;  //bring all overloads of methodA into B's scope
  virtual void methodA(int) {}
};
```

Comment: Hit it on the head - thanks very much that has been bugging me for ages.